# Handlebar object key inside of array

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

When using handlebars, is there a way of accessing an object's key if it is within an array?

```
  var context = {
people: [ 
  { firstName: 'Homer', lastName: 'Simpson' },
  { firstName: 'Peter', lastName: 'Griffin' },
  { firstName: 'Eric', lastName: 'Cartman' },
  { firstName: 'Kenny', lastName: 'McCormick' },
  { firstName: 'Bart', lastName: 'Simpson' }
  ]
};
```

Handlebars has an inbuilt helper to access object keys, but it doesn't seem to work when chained.

```
{{#each myObject}}
Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Is there a known structure to return:

```
firstName: Homer lastName: Simpson
```

Comment: As close as I've been able to get:
`{{#each people}}
      {{#each this}}
        <li>{{@key}}{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}`